# When I am running the example in the mockito official documentation, an error InvalidUseOfMatchersException is reported

Tags: mockito

I am running the example([https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html](11. Stubbing with callbacks)),it prompts me：

`You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing. Examples of correct usage of argument matchers: when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null); doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(any()); verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))`

**I am very confused, where did I violate this rule, or there is something wrong with his example**

```
type here
```

This is my method:

```
public class TestMockWeb {
    public String someMethod(String arg){
        return "run!!!";
    }
}
```

This is my test method:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestMockWebTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private TestMockWeb mock;

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethod() {
        when(mock.someMethod(anyString())).thenAnswer(
                new Answer() {
                    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                        Object mock = invocation.getMock();
                        return "called with arguments: " + Arrays.toString(args);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

This is exception:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended

org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at com.iluwatar.TestMockWebTest.testSomeMethod(TestMockWebTest.java:27)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(any());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object 
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.


    at com.iluwatar.TestMockWebTest.testSomeMethod(TestMockWebTest.java:27)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:55)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:100)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:107)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:41)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
```

**
Can anyone tell me what is the difference between this code and his example? （Is it caused by my use of @InjectMocks？）How should it be modified to make it work properly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Your use of `@InjectMocks` is wrong, that should be `@Mock`.

Comment: OK，looks as I guessed, thank you

Comment: `@InjectMocks` does not create a mock object. Section 11 of the docs does not mention @InjectMocks. Section 9 shows how to use the annotations: https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#9